# The support of nonnegative integer valued measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$, where $E$ is a metric space, $\mathcal{E}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $E$, and $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite nonnegative integer valued measure, i.e. $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure and
$$\mu : \mathcal{E}\to\mathbb{N}\cup \{+\infty\}$$
I know when $E$ is a polish space, the support of $\mu$ is a countable points of $E$.

But if we only suppose $E$ is a metric space, is the support of $\mu$ still a countable points of $E$?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your proof in the polish case? how do you use the completeness assumption?

Comment: @mookid I think using the separate assumption we can find a closed bound set $B_1$(ball or square) which has a positive measure. Then we can also find a smaller closed set $B_2$ contained in $B_1$. Finally we get a sequence of decreasing closed set with diameter tends to $0$. By the complete assumption the intersection of these sets is a point. And this point have a positive measure. Am I right?

Comment: Nice. The framework of metric space seems too permissive: consider the discrete topology. you may hope for a result if you ask regularity of $\mu$, but I am not sure.

Comment: You need at least $\sigma$-finiteness of the measure for the conclusion, also in Polish spaces. Without that, the counting measure on an uncountable Polish space is a counterexample.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right. Added, thanks!